# Why am I getting the error "Cannot assign to the result of this expression" when checking for the class of a sender?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to make a function that will check the class of the sender and act accordingly but for some reason I get the error "Cannot assign to the result of this expression" with the first condition. Can anyone enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong? The error appears on the `clipToBounds` line.
 Here's the code:

```
func setupContactIcons(sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (sender!.isKindOfClass(UIVisualEffectView)) {
        sender!.layer.cornerRadius = sender!.frame.size.width/2
        sender!.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }
```

Bonus: Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way of doing this would be to use `if let` in conjunction with `as?`:

```
func setupContactIcons(sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let view = sender as? UIVisualEffectView {
        view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.width/2
        view.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

which, incidentally, will also eliminate the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to optimize my code while learning new ways of doing things 